# How to clear cart after logout in opencart 2.x?

Tags: opencart2.x

I am using Opencart 2.x version and wants to clear cart when customer logout their account.

So please help me to achieve this task. I tried previous solutions but its not working for me (opencart 2.x) version all of are for Version 1.5.x to 1.6.x

Thanks..

Comment: It all works automatically. You do not need to clear it manually. When customer logout then all cart products get stored in a table and cart session is cleared.

Comment: If your version is `< 2.0.3.1` then it is stored in the `customer` table and in newer versions it is stored in the `cart` table.

Comment: Thanks i got enough info from you to finish my task...Thanks a lot..